With my Next.JS app acting as a BFF, how do I make authorized requests to a downstream api on the same keycloak client?
The end goal of what I want to accomplish is to have my Next.JS app act as a BFF for my .Net Core Api and authenticate to that api leveraging the server side session that the user has already established with keycloak within Next.JS.
Here is the architecture of my application:

I currently have my Next.JS app setup with a Keycloak provider. Based on some information I found here: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7913
import NextAuth, { Account, AuthOptions, TokenSet } from "next-auth";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    accessToken: string;
    expiresAt: number;
    refreshToken: string;
    error?: "RefreshAccessTokenError";
  }
}

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, account }) => {
      if (account) {
        return {
          ...token,
          accessToken: account.access_token || "",
          expiresAt: account.expires_at || 0,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token || "",
        };
      }

      if (Date.now() < token.expiresAt * 1000) {
        return token;
      }

      return await refreshToken(token);
    },
    redirect: async ({ baseUrl }) => {
      return baseUrl;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      //console.log("session", session, "token", token);
      // If we want to make the accessToken available in components, then we have to explicitly forward it here.
      return { ...session, token: token.accessToken, error: token.error };
    },
  },
};

async function refreshToken(token: JWT): Promise<JWT> {
  try {
    const tokenEndpoint = `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

    const response = await fetch(tokenEndpoint, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      }),
      method: "POST",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res: TokenSet) => res);
    console.log("refreshToken response", response);
    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: response.access_token || "",
      expiresAt: response.expires_at || 0,
      refreshToken: response.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error refreshing access token", error);
    return { ...token, error: "RefreshAccessTokenError" as const };
  }
}
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

Using this setup I'm able to get the JWT access token from a server side api route in Next.JS and pass that as a bearer token to my .net core API.
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "../auth/[...nextauth]/route";

export async function GET() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  const validSession =
    session && session.token && session.error !== "RefreshAccessTokenError";
  if (!validSession) {
    return Response.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
  }
  const res = await fetch("http://api:8080/WeatherForecast", {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${session.token}` },
  });
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    return Response.json({ error: "Failed to fetch data" }, { status: 500 });
  }

  return Response.json(await res.json());
}

Called from here which passes existing session cookies to the route.
async function getData(token: string) {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: new Headers(headers()),
  });
  // The return value is *not* serialized
  // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.

  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data", await res.json());
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  const validSession =
    session && session.error !== "RefreshAccessTokenError" && session.token;
  const data = validSession ? await getData(session?.token) : [];

This works... mostly. My problem is that the refresh token expires long before the session and the user can still have an active session while not being able to refresh the JWT token. I feel like I can maybe solve that, but it just feels so messy which leads me to think I'm missing something fundamental here. Do I really need the JWT token to make a secure call to my .net core api that is on the same keycloak client as the next js app? Can I leverage the existing session somehow to make this call?
